# How JEditorPane scroll to specified HTML link

Tags: java, html, swing, jscrollpane, jeditorpane

I use a JEditorPane to dispaly a html file on my machine, this html has a link named "skip to main content" which will lead user to the middle of the same page; but I want it automaticaly scroll to the middle of the page just with the dialog been set visible, I tried JEditorPane.scrollToReference(), it is not work.

any one can help?

Answer (score 4):

You can't invoke the scrollToReference() method until the components have been realized. That is the dialog has been packed or made visible.

The easiest way to do this is to wrap the scrollToReference() method is a SwingUitilities.invokeLater. Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EditorPaneScroll extends JPanel 
{
    private JEditorPane html;

    public EditorPaneScroll()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        String text = "<html>one<br>two<br><a name =\"three\"></a>three<br>four<br>five<br>six<br>seven<br>eight<br>nine<br>ten</html>";
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(text);

        html = new JEditorPane();
        html.setContentType("text/html");

        try
        {
            html.read(reader, null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( html );
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(400, 100) );
        add( scrollPane );

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                html.scrollToReference("three");
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("EditorPaneScroll");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new EditorPaneScroll() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```